# How to Create Model From Two Different Controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `ProTip` model created using scaffold generator. All actions except for `index` and `show` require you to be an admin.

I would like to allow users to submit their own `ProTip`s but store them in a queue until someone has a chance to approve them.

I can think of a couple ways to do this:

1. Create an entirely different model for a `UserSubmittedProTip` with the same fields as `ProTip`. Create a new `UserSubmittedProTipController` with `index`, `new` and `create` actions. On the `create` action I could create a new `ProTip` and copy the properties from the `UserSubmittedProTip` to it before saving to the database. I could require admin for the `index` action and could use it to perform approvals.
2. Create a new `SubmitController` with only `new` and `create` actions. Create a view that somehow shares the `ProTip`'s `_form` partial  but knows which controller to submit to. On the `create` action I could set the `ProTip.approved` to `false` before saving. I would then have to create a mechanism for approving.

The first method seems the easiest since I don't know how to implement the second. Both methods feel a little clumsy and I'm wondering what the best practice is for this type of problem.

**Are these the only two ways to solve this problem? 
If not, what would be smarter? Otherwise, which is closer to a best-practice or are they both glaringly wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend the first solution.

With your scenario, there's no reason to actually use two controllers for this if you don't really want to.

If the current user is an admin, you can simply create the object normally.

If the current user is not an admin, you create the object but set a boolean that the item needs approval, Or do the reverse.... set the "approved" flag when you're an admin.

When an admin looks at the list action, you can show the additional "approval" column.

```
def create
  @protip = Protip.new(params[:protip]
  # I'm assuming you have logic to determine if the user is an admin.
  # I usually encapsulate that in a method on the user model. So
  # my code would look like this:
  @protip.approved = true if current_user.is_an_admin
  if @protip.save
     ... do your normal stuff


end
```

Ensure you have a scope for the approved protips

```
scope :approved, where(:approved => true)
```

And always show those.

```
@protips = Protip.approved
```

If you did want to keep them separate, you can certainly reuse partials. When you do a call to render, you can specify where to get the partial from.

```
render "/protips/_form"
```

How's that for a start?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the detailed reply. Sometimes with rails I need to just take a step back and realize there is an easier way because there usually is.